# Дважды повторяется вывод программы. Как устранить

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа проверяет, является ли поданная на вход последовательность чисел монотонной (возрастающей или убывающей), в том числе нестрого. Программа получает на вход последовательность целых чисел a1, …, an, разделённых пробелами (-100 ≤ ai ≤ 100, 1 ≤ n ≤ 100) и печатает одну из двух строк YES или NO.

Вот программа, она работает, но выводит два раза один и тот же ответ. Как это все объединить, чтобы она этого не делала? Заранее благодарю.

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]

prev = a[0]
c1 = True
for i in a[1:]:
    if prev <= i:
        prev = i
    else:
         print("No")
         c1=False
         break
else: print("Yes")


prev = a[0]
c2 = True
for i in a[1:]:
    if prev >= i:
        prev = i
        
    else:
         print("No")
         c2=False
         break
else: print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

> она работает, но выводит два раза один и тот же ответ.

У вас один вариант записи логики кода, только один цикл выводит результат для монотонно возрастающей функции, а другой для монотонно убывающей. Например, при вводе последовательности `1 2 3 4`, первый цикл выведет `Yes`, другой `No`. Как у вас получилось, что выводится один и тот же результат, причём верный, непонятно. Скорее всего вы вводите данные для постоянной функции. Я могу предложить свой вариант логики. Вы легко сможете переделать код под свою логику:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ") if i.strip()]

c1 = False
c2 = False

for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    if a[i] < a[i + 1]:
        c1 = True
         
    elif a[i] > a[i + 1]:
        c2 = True


if c1 and not c2:
    print('Монотонно возрастающая функция')
elif c2 and not c1:
    print('Монотонно убывающая функция')
elif c1 and c2:
    print('Функция убывает и возрастает')
else:
    print('Функция постоянна')
```